# Freeze and crash of React-Native application after returning from background mode, or switching from another application

Tags: android, ios, crash, react-native, freeze

I use React-Native for IOS and Android, and my application freezes and sometimes crashes after coming back from background mode or switching between the applications. 
The freezing happens on any of the screens and is unpredictable. 
Under the “freezing”, I mean the buttons may not be working for 10 seconds (sometimes more), although ListView and ScrollView respond to the scroll with no holdback. 
After application restart, it works properly.

The application has more than 10 screens, has local AsyncStorage storage, cloud real-time database Firebase (javascript library), PubNub real-time messaging service is activated (javascript library). 
Below is the package.json, in which there are the installed modules.

```
{
  "name": "MyApplication",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@remobile/react-native-splashscreen": "^1.0.3",
    "firebase": "^2.4.2",
    "firebase-token-generator": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-native": "^0.24.1",
    "react-native-accordion": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-android-blurryoverlay": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-blur": "^0.7.11",
    "react-native-button": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-checkbox-field": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-extra-dimensions-android": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-gcm-android": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-gifted-messenger": "0.1.4",
    "react-native-gifted-spinner": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.20.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^1.5.12",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-radio-button-classic": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-realtimemessaging-android": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.22.23",
    "react-native-share": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.0.12",
    "react-native-system-notification": "^0.1.11"
  }
}
```

Need you assistance with these freezing and crashes. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm encountering the same thing. Thanks

Comment: The problem: too many requests to the AsyncStorage at short time crash the android app. Responses from realtime database firebase every time call  AsyncStorage methods. The solution was to change algorithm and architecture of the application.

Comment: I'm seeing similar issues, but on react-native iOS. My hunch is that my issue is related. What about the algorithm/architecture did you change to fix this?

Comment: I'd like to see the example as well. I'm using AsyncStorage on IOS with this issue and I am curious what your code looked like before and after this fix

Comment: Any update please?